# When in the page lifecycle we can assign master page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages, page-lifecycle

I know ViewState is available between InitComplete and Preload events in LoadViewSate method. Similarly, I want to know in which page lifecycle event can we assign a master page for a particular page?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Because the master page and content page are merged during the
>   initialization stage of page processing, a master page  must be
>   assigned before then. Typically, you assign a master page dynamically
>   during the PreInit stage

On `Page PreInit` event

```
void Page_PreInit(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.MasterPageFile = "~/MyMaster.master";
}
```

Read [Working with ASP.NET Master Pages Programmatically](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c8y19k6h.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

From: [ASP.NET Page Life Cycle Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms178472%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Page Event

Typical Use

**PreInit**

Raised after the start stage is complete and before the initialization stage begins. Use this event for the following:

Check the IsPostBack property to determine whether this is the first time the page is being processed. The IsCallback and IsCrossPagePostBack properties have also been set at this time.

- Create or re-create dynamic controls.
- Set a master page dynamically.
- Set the Theme property dynamically.
- Read or set profile property
  values.

**Note**    If the request is a postback, the values of the controls have not yet been restored from view state. If you set a control property at this stage, its value might be overwritten in the next event.

From: [Attaching Master Pages Dynamically](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/c8y19k6h%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

In addition to specifying a master page declaratively (in the *`@ Page directive or in the configuration file`*), you can attach a master page dynamically to a content page. Because the master page and content page are merged during the initialization stage of page processing, a master page must be assigned before then. Typically, you assign a master page dynamically during the [PreInit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/system.web.ui.page.preinit%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) stage, as in the following example:

```
void Page_PreInit(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.MasterPageFile = "~/DefaultMaster.master";
}
```

**Edit:**

*Source:* [ASP.NET Master Pages - How Master Pages Work](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/wtxbf3hh%28v=vs.100%29.aspx#HowMasterPagesWork)
You can use @Page directive also to specify master page.

```
<% @ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Master.master" Title="Content Page 1" %>
```